# JPA still finds entities after it deleted them

Tags: jpa, entitymanager

I have a `OneToMany` relation from A to B (A references a list Bs).

When I delete a B using either `entityManager.remove(b)` or `a.getBs().remove(b)`or both, and load A again : the deleted B will still appear in the list THOUGH it has been effectively removed from the database! I tried with and without `Cascade.ALL` on the relation with no success..

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you show us your mapping (annotations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do both (unless you use delete orphans).  If you do both it should be gone.  Ensure you remove it from the correct managed a, not a detached a.  Ensure the a actually contains the b to begin with.

You could always call refresh() to confirm that the database state was correct.

Comment: Thanks, I chose the 'delete orphans' solution, it works nicely.